# Named Parameter not working in my script

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a PS function that takes a -Computername parameter. Here is the code I'm using:

```
function Get-Foo {
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,Position=0,ValueFromPipeline=$True,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
    [string[]]$Computername = $env:COMPUTERNAME
)
```

However, when I run the function as `Get-Foo -Computername BAZ` it never passes the named parameter BAZ, but instead always uses the value of `$env:COMPUTERNAME`. I'm generally new to PowerShell, and definitely to writing functions, so hopefully someone can quickly see where I'm going wrong here. I cut and modified the `param` line from another script that does work, so I don't know why it doesn't work here... Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you calling it? It worked for me in all the various types of way it could be set:

```
function Get-Foo {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,Position=0,ValueFromPipeline=$True,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
        [string[]]$Computername = $env:COMPUTERNAME

    )
    Write-Host $Computername
}

Get-Foo -COmputername "hi"
"hi" | Get-Foo
$obj = New-Object PsObject -Property @{ Computername='hi' }
$obj | Get-Foo
```

All of which output "hi".

Comment: I'm not seeing what you are seeing... When I run that exact script, I get no output. I am running PS 3.0 on Win8 CTP, but I wouldn't think that would matter...

Comment: Also just tried it (on the same Win8 machine) using PS 2.0, same thing - no output. Very very strange...

Comment: OK, it's because I'm unlearned :) I was calling the function as just "Get-Foo" without a parameter. So it was always taking the default :-P  And in the above tests, I just copied the function block, and tried to run it as a script with a parameter at the command line. Obviously I have much to learn... Thanks for the help anyhow!